# javafx TableView how to edit a TextField on external TextArea control and return the result to the field properly

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have been trying to accomplish editing of a cell in `TableView` which has long text on it. for that I have to pass the value to an external window `TextArea` and return the result to the field, but I can not get the value changed but after pushing ENTER and then select a new row with the mouse. The keyboard gets frozen. If I click same row the field doe snot change

My code is

```
contact_view.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue obs, Object oldSelection, Object newSelection) {
        if (newSelection != null) {
            TableView.TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = contact_view.getSelectionModel();
            ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
            tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);

            row = tablePosition.getRow();
            col = tablePosition.getColumn();
            Object colname = tablePosition.getTableColumn().getId();
            val = (String) notes.getCellData(row);
            String tmp="";
            tmp = String.valueOf(cntac_name.getCellData(row));   
            frozenCol.setText(tmp);
            System.out.println("Hola mundo 563 "+" "+row +" "+col+" "+val+" "+colname+" "+tmp);
//          frozenCol.setText((java.lang.String) val);
            if(col == 21) {
                notes.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Contact>forTableColumn());
                notes.setOnEditStart(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Contact, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(CellEditEvent<Contact, String> t) {
                        ((Contact) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setNotes(t.getNewValue());
                        String cscode =t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()).cstmr_code;
                        String newValue =t.getNewValue();
//                      notes.setText((java.lang.String) newValue);
                        System.out.println("Hola mundo 615 "+t.getNewValue()+" "+t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()).cstmr_code);
                        String ok=String.valueOf(cssEditorFld.getText());
                        System.out.println("Hola mundo 617 "+" "+row +" "+col+" "+val+" "+cntac_name.getCellData(row)+" "+cssEditorFld.getText()+" "+ok);   
    //                  boolean r = CstmersDBConnection.UpdateSingleContact(cscode, cntac_code, colname, newValue);
                        //setCellFactory(SetEditorTxtArea());

                        Stage s=new Stage();
                        Object p =cntac_name.getCellData(row);
                        s.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                        s.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
                        s.setResizable(true);
                        s.setTitle(String.valueOf(p));
                        Group root = new Group();
                        GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
                        gridpane.setPadding(new Insets(1));
                        gridpane.setHgap(1);
                        gridpane.setVgap(1);
                        cssEditorFld.setText(String.valueOf(val));
                        cssEditorFld.setPrefRowCount(20);
                        cssEditorFld.setPrefColumnCount(150);
                        cssEditorFld.setWrapText(true);
                        cssEditorFld.setPrefWidth(300);
                        GridPane.setHalignment(cssEditorFld, HPos.CENTER);  
                        gridpane.add(cssEditorFld, 0, 1);                
                        HBox hbox = addHBox();
                        gridpane.add(hbox, 0, 2);                
                        root.getChildren().add(gridpane);
                        s.setScene(new Scene(root));
                        s.show();
                        buttonYs.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                                System.out.println(" Clicked Yes");
                                String ok=String.valueOf(cssEditorFld.getText());
                                n= true;
                                s.hide();

                                ((Contact) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setNotes(cssEditorFld.getText());
                                System.out.println("Hola mundo 627 "+" "+row +" "+col+" "+cssEditorFld.getText()+" "+((Contact) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).notes);   
                            }
                        });        
                        System.out.println("Hola mundo 631 "+" "+row +" "+col+" "+val+" "+p+" "+cntac_name.getCellData(row)+" "+cssEditorFld.getText());   
                        buttonNo.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                                System.out.println(" Clicked No");
                                n = false;
                                s.hide();
                            }
                        });

                    }

                });
```

Comment: The editing API for table views (and other virtualized controls) is for editing directly in the cell. If you want to open a new window with an editor in it of some kind, I would not use this approach at all: it's not at all clear why you are using a `TextFieldTableCell` (which causes the cell to display a text field to edit the value) here if you want to edit the value in a different `TextArea`. Just use a cell factory that registers a mouse handler on the cells and displays the window.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `cellFactory` in a listener to the selection model is a bad practice. Rather than doing it this way, create a custom `TableCell` in the `cellFactory` for the column customize the editing by overwriting `commitEdit`, `cancelEdit` and `startEdit`.

Example:

```
TableView<StringProperty> tv = new TableView(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new SimpleStringProperty("ajds bnas röu bngöspui rgöin röeisnpnhn reishn reinnb ökb rhkbhkbn afeae"),
        new SimpleStringProperty("aap nja öaw njeaj nanja nja njja n"))
);

TableColumn<StringProperty, String> col = new TableColumn<>();

tv.getColumns().add(col);
tv.setEditable(true);

col.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue());
col.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<StringProperty, String>() {

    private final Text text;

    private Stage editingStage;

    {
        text = new Text();
        text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(column.widthProperty());
        setGraphic(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        closeStage();
    }

    private void closeStage() {
        if (editingStage != null && editingStage.isShowing()) {
            editingStage.setOnHidden(null);
            editingStage.hide();
            editingStage = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void commitEdit(String newValue) {
        super.commitEdit(newValue);
        closeStage();
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();

        // create editing ui
        Button cancel = new Button("Cancel");
        cancel.setCancelButton(true);
        cancel.setOnAction(evt -> cancelEdit());

        TextArea editor = new TextArea(getItem());

        Button commit = new Button("OK");
        commit.setOnAction(evt -> commitEdit(editor.getText()));

        VBox vbox = new VBox(10, editor, commit, cancel);

        // display editing window
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        editingStage = new Stage();
        editingStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        editingStage.initOwner(getScene().getWindow());
        editingStage.setScene(scene);

        editingStage.setOnHidden(evt -> this.cancelEdit());
        editingStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        cancelEdit();
        text.setText(item);
    }

});
```

Comment: Curious: doesn't `Bindings.max(column.widthProperty(), Double.MIN_VALUE)` always evaluate to `column.widthProperty()`? Or are you doing something clever to work around a corner-case?

Comment: Not necessary, you're right. Got confused with a similar problem where this would be necessary...

Comment: Thanks a lot Gentlemen I will try to implement James_D solution and get back to you. It seems this is the correct approach. Thanks again for helping me so quick

Comment: Thanks a lot James_D it works beautiful, and I will implement it immediately and get back to you. About this there is no other solution on Internet and I have searched for several days and referred to several possible sources for help but this is beautiful. Thanks again

Comment: James again thanks a lot for your solution. It has been implemented and works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the `TableView` editing API if you intend to edit the value externally to the table (it's not really clear how you would do this, or what the `TextFieldTableCell` you use is for if you intend to edit the data elsewhere).

Just use a cell factory that opens the new window to perform the editing when this cell is double-clicked. You can pass a callback (represented, for example, as a `Consumer`) to the window for updating the value in the table model.

Here is a SSCCE. The "Item" column edits in the "usual" way using the built-in `TextFieldTableCell`: the "Description" column edits using an external window.

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class ExternalEditingTable extends Application {

    private void showEditingWindow(Window owner, String currentValue, Consumer<String> commitHandler) {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initOwner(owner);
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea(currentValue);

        Button okButton = new Button("OK");
        okButton.setDefaultButton(true);
        okButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            commitHandler.accept(textArea.getText());
            stage.hide();
        });

        Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");
        cancelButton.setCancelButton(true);
        cancelButton.setOnAction(e -> stage.hide());

        HBox buttons = new HBox(5, okButton, cancelButton);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        buttons.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(textArea, null, null, buttons, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Item, String> nameCol = column("Item", Item::nameProperty);

        // just use standard editing approach as data is "small":
        nameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

        TableColumn<Item, String> descriptionCol = column("Description", Item::descriptionProperty);

        // set up this column to show an editing window when double-clicked:
        descriptionCol.setCellFactory(tc -> {

            TableCell<Item, String> cell = new TableCell<Item, String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    setText(empty ? null : item);
                }
            };

            cell.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && ! cell.isEmpty()) {
                    showEditingWindow(table.getScene().getWindow(), cell.getItem(), newValue -> {
                        Item item = table.getItems().get(cell.getIndex());
                        item.setDescription(newValue);
                    });
                }
            });

            return cell ;
        });

        table.getColumns().add(nameCol);
        table.getColumns().add(descriptionCol);

        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 20 ; i++) {
            table.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i, "This is a long and\nwordy description of item "+i));
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(table, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, Property<T>> prop) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> prop.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty description = new SimpleStringProperty() ;
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty() ;

        public Item(String name, String description) {
            setName(name);
            setDescription(description);
        }

        public final StringProperty descriptionProperty() {
            return this.description;
        }


        public final String getDescription() {
            return this.descriptionProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setDescription(final String description) {
            this.descriptionProperty().set(description);
        }


        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }


        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```